# I'm facing problems troubleshooting my vb.net code

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to update data in my excel database but it keeps giving me an error "Cannot covert from string "" to integer". I guess there is something wrong with it as I am not good with vb.net. I'm using an excel database. Only the first combox1 part is working without any error.

```
 Dim AreaCode As String
    Dim x As Integer
    MsgBox("Do you want to update the records?")
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        Try
            AreaCode = ACTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(0).Value = ACTextBox.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

    Dim MetropolitanArea As String
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        Try
            MetropolitanArea = MATextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(1).Value = ACTextBox.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

    Dim AnnualFixedArea As Integer
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(2) Then
        Try
            AnnualFixedArea = AFCTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(2).Value = AFCTextBox.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If

    Dim WagePerHour As String
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(3) Then
        Try
            WagePerHour = TextBoxWPH.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(3).Value = TextBoxWPH.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: _AnnualFixedArea_ is an integer but you are trying to assign to it a string. This is not allowed when Option Strict is set to On. (As it should always be). You need to use Convert.ToInt32 or better Int32.TryParse to trasform a string into a numeric value (Even if your string contains only numeric characters)

Comment: I've tried converting it. But it still isn't working

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an integer as a string as below

```
Dim AnnualFixedArea As Integer
AnnualFixedArea = AFCTextBox.Text
```

In order to set your integer to the value of the TextBox, use the below

```
Dim AnnualFixedArea As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(s, AnnualFixedArea) Then
    AnnualFixedArea = -1
End If
```

This will set `AnnualFixedArea` to be the value of the `TextBox` if it can be parsed or it will set it to be -1.

See [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First, Excel is not a database. It is a spreadsheet program. Databases are MS Sql Server, MySql, Access, etc.

It is sort of silly to ask if the user wants to update when all they can do is click OK.

I am not sure of the purpose of all those variables when you just assign the text boxes' text property directly to the grid. A Select Case is a bit cleaner here. Since x is never anything but 0 just use 0. There are no networks or connections going on here so why the Try...End Try?

Did you realize that you have assigned ACTextBox.Text to two different cells in the grid?

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = ACTextBox.Text
        Case 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(1).Value = ACTextBox.Text
        Case 2
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(2).Value = AFCTextBox.Text
        Case 3
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(3).Value = TextBoxWPH.Text
    End Select
End Sub
```